# date time joda api is displaying incorrect zone code for some zone ids

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, timezone, jodatime

I was trying to format date time with formatter `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z` with joda api for id `Australia/Yancowinna` . My expectation is, it should display 3 letter short code (e.g: IST, GMT, EDT etc) for zone but instead of that it is displaying +10:30. How ever its is displaying correct zone code for most of the other Ids.

Here is my code

```
package com.rais;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

public class DateClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID("Australia/Yancowinna"));        
        DateTime datetime = new DateTime("2015-01-13T14:30:00.000+10:30");
        System.out.println("Original time = "+datetime);
        System.out.println("Original time zone = "+datetime.getZone());
        System.out.println("Original time toString(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z)= "+datetime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z"));   

    }
}
```

And here is output

```
Original time = 2015-01-13T14:30:00.000+10:30
Original time zone = Australia/Broken_Hill
Original time toString(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z)= 2015-01-13 14:30 +10:30
```

If we work with zone id `Asia/Amman`, it displaying correct zone code in case of windows but not displaying zone code in case of linux.

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time Is Correct

An offset of `+10:30` is indeed correct for DST IN `Australia/Yancowinna`.

Reporting the time zone as `Australia/Broken_Hill` is correct as well. [That name is primary](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia/Broken_Hill), with `Australia/Yancowinna` being secondary.

## Avoid 3 & 4 Letter Codes

Those 3 or 4 letter codes are neither standardized nor unique.

Does `IST` mean Ireland Standard Time or India Standard Time? It means both, as just one example.

Furthermore those codes refer to Standard time and Daylight Saving Time. Those are not time zones, they are the *result* of a time zone being applied. A time zone is an offset from UTC ( hours and minutes) *and* a set of rules for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) as needed for past, present, and future date-time values.

Both Joda-Time and java.time wisely avoid those 3/4 letter codes. So should you.

Those libraries do make an attempt to parse such codes as input. But given their problems, I suggest avoiding such imports. Stick with [ISO 8601](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format strings, used by default in both Joda-Time and java.time. The java.time library extends that standard format by appending the [proper time zone name](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in brackets, in addition to the offset. A wise approach as all information is included for translating back and forth between time zones.

Comment: Hi @Basil Bourque, thanks for great great explanation. I understand the explanation given by you. My problem is that, I have to make a webservice call which will require that short code and if absent or not correct then send a failed report. I need to send these short code with request

Comment: @RaisAlam First beware of such a web service. If those developers don't know to avoid 3-letter codes, they likely will have other problems with date-time handling. Secondly, you could experiment with the lowercase `z` formatting code in Joda-Time. But that is hit-or-miss because of all the duplicate values in those non-standardized codes. Perhaps peruse the source-code of Joda-Time to see how it translates the `z` to a code. If your data involves a limited set of such codes, I would simply hard-code into the strings with your own code.